# Under VMWare, Node.js Azure Web Role doesn't run

Tags: node.js, azure, vmware

Under VMWare Fusion, with Azure SDK 1.8 and the node additions, the [hello-world instructions](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/) do not work for me. Has anybody discovered a fix?

### Reproducing, more quickly

1. Open a non-administrator Powershell
2. `New-AzureServiceProject`
3. `Add-AzureNodeWebRole`
4. `Azure-StartEmulator -Launch`

The web browser opens (Chrome), and the response is always empty. I have seen this under both bridged and shared-connection networking, and also from the host machine. Logs (I think they're logs) in the compute emulator and in apphome/log.txt reveal nothing. Running `node server.js` directly, meanwhile, produces a working server.

I mention VMWare Fusion specifically because these steps work for me at the office, where I'm not running a virtual machine.

I'm a bit green on all things Windows, which I started using *only* for Azure tools. It may help me to know where to look.

Comment: Is there somebody else out there who has had a different experience?

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that the azure storage emulator uses some ports VMWave is using, but not pretty sure if this is your case.